# Typescript class decorator is not able to get class name from `target.constructor.name`

Tags: typescript

Why is `target.constructor.name` not resolved correctly for a class decorator, but it works for method decorator ?

example:

```js
function myClassDecorator(target: any) {
 console.log(target.constructor.name)
}

function myMethodDecorator(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
 console.log(target.constructor.name)
}

@myClassDecorator
class MyClass {
 @myMethodDecorator
 foo() {}
}

const myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.foo()
```

this prints the following

```
Function
MyClass
```

Why is `target.constructor.name` being resolved differently for both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class decorator is given the class itself, so your class decorator should be using `target.name`:

```
function myClassDecorator(target: any) {
  console.log(target.name)
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJX8DN)